# Alternative for PERCENTILE_CONT in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, oracle, mariadb, analytic-functions

[image]

I want to calculate percentile_cont on this table.
In Oracle, the query would be

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) FROM sometable;
```

What would be it's alternative in MariaDB/MySQL?

Comment: Please define `percentile_cont` or show us what data you want from that `SELECT` based on your sample table.

Comment: Do you need the `WITHIN GROUP` feature?

Answer (score 4):

While MariaDB 10.3.3 has support for these functions in the form of window functions ([see Lukasz Szozda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50748747/521799)), you can emulate them using window functions in MySQL 8 as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_value(matrix_value) OVER (
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN p <= 0.05 THEN p END DESC /* NULLS LAST */
) x,
FROM (
  SELECT
    matrix_value,
    percent_rank() OVER (ORDER BY matrix_value) p,
  FROM some_table
) t;
```

[I've blogged about this more in detail here](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/28/how-to-emulate-percentile_disc-in-mysql-and-other-rdbms/).

Comment: Great solution, Lukas, but on your blog you emulate just PERCENTILE_DISC. About PERCENTILE_CONT you only mention it's similar but more tricky. Would you find time for a blog post emulating PERCENTILE_CONT as well? I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: If it helps, I found this runs about 3x faster on my MySQL 8:

    SELECT p
    FROM (
      SELECT
        matrix_value,
        percent_rank() OVER (ORDER BY matrix_value) p,
      FROM some_table
    ) t
    WHERE p <= 0.5
    ORDER BY p desc
    LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 3):

`MariaDB 10.3.3` introduced `PERCENTILE_CONT`, `PERCENTILE_DISC`, and `MEDIAN` windowed functions.

> [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/percentile_cont/)
>
> **PERCENTILE_CONT()** (standing for continuous percentile) is an ordered set aggregate function which can also be used as a window function. It returns a value which corresponds to the given fraction in the sort order. If required, it will interpolate between adjacent input items.
>
> ```
> SELECT name, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY star_rating) 
>         OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS pc 
> FROM book_rating;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function for this in either MariaDB or MySQL, so you have to solve this on the SQL level (or by adding a user defined function written in C ...)

This might help with coming up with a SQL solution:

http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2008/07/calculating-nth-percentile-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

[*MariaDB 10.2*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/) has windowing functions.

For MySQL / older MariaDB, and assuming you just want the Nth percentile for a single set of values.

This is best done form app code, but could be built into a stored routine.

1. Count the total number of rows:  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl`.
2. Construct and execute a `SELECT` with `LIMIT n,1` where `n` is computed as the percentile times the count, then filled into the query.

If you need to interpolate between two values, it gets messier.  Do you need that, too?

Comment: Yes, it has but starting from 10.3.3 it supports `PERCENTILE_CONT` natively

Comment: @lad2025 - I sketched out how to do it.